# Combine two json key value as 1 item in Python

Tags: python

I have a list like this :

```
{'serial1': 'BPCE-RNHC-25G8', 'subject1': 'EMP004', 'serial2': '7QF2-6HI9-XKZZ', 'subject2': 'EMP005', 'serial3': '8FIW-9JRB-NY4J', 'subject3': 'EMP003', 'serial4': 'SG8P-YQKG-ZV3C', 'subject4': 'EMP002', 'serial5': 'PBF7-WZ
HT-WPZR', 'subject5': 'EMP001'}
```

When I send this list over my html template using `for` loop , the `serial` and `subject` value is separated and divide into 2 column which represent:
[image]

My desire output is the  `serial` and `subject` appear on the same column for the same record. For example:
[image]

As you can see my dict has `serial1,2,3..` and `subject 1,2,3..`. How can I combine the `serial(n)` with `subject(n)` as one item in the json list? So that i could display it on my HTML  as 1 item?

Comment: First thing is, what you are showing is not a list, its Python dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the keys are only `subjectN` and `serialN`, and N <= len(my_dict)/2 (ie. there are no other keys, you don't skip any numbers), we can just merge them nicely.

```py
my_dict = {'serial1': 'BPCE-RNHC-25G8', 'subject1': 'EMP004', 'serial2': '7QF2-6HI9-XKZZ', 'subject2': 'EMP005', 'serial3': '8FIW-9JRB-NY4J', 'subject3': 'EMP003', 'serial4': 'SG8P-YQKG-ZV3C', 'subject4': 'EMP002', 'serial5': 'PBF7-WZHT-WPZR', 'subject5': 'EMP001'}

merged = {f'merged{i}': my_dict[f'subject{i}']+': '+my_dict[f'serial{i}'] for i in range(1, len(my_dict)//2+1)}
```

You can rename your new key. If you want it as a list:

```
merged = [my_dict[f'subject{i}']+': '+my_dict[f'serial{i}'] for i in range(1, len(my_dict)//2+1)]
```

**What this does:**

`i` goes from `1` to `len(my_dict)//2` (inclusive; range end is exclusive)

resulting list/dict is just a string concatenation of subject with given number, ': ', and serial with given number.

**Result on the given example**

```
>>> merged = {f'merged{i}': my_dict[f'subject{i}']+': '+my_dict[f'serial{i}'] for i in range(1, len(my_dict)//2+1)}
>>> merged
{'merged1': 'EMP004: BPCE-RNHC-25G8', 'merged2': 'EMP005: 7QF2-6HI9-XKZZ', 'merged3': 'EMP003: 8FIW-9JRB-NY4J', 'merged4': 'EMP002: SG8P-YQKG-ZV3C', 'merged5': 'EMP001: PBF7-WZHT-WPZR'}
>>>
>>> merged = [my_dict[f'subject{i}']+': '+my_dict[f'serial{i}'] for i in range(1, len(my_dict)//2+1)] 
>>> merged
['EMP004: BPCE-RNHC-25G8', 'EMP005: 7QF2-6HI9-XKZZ', 'EMP003: 8FIW-9JRB-NY4J', 'EMP002: SG8P-YQKG-ZV3C', 'EMP001: PBF7-WZHT-WPZR']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to join the key/value pairs by `:` , you can use join for each key/value pair in the iteration using `dict.items()`, you can do it in a List-Comprehension to do it for the entire dictionary.

```py
>>> [': '.join(t) for t in d.items()]

['serial1: BPCE-RNHC-25G8', 'subject1: EMP004', 'serial2: 7QF2-6HI9-XKZZ', 'subject2: EMP005', 'serial3: 8FIW-9JRB-NY4J', 'subject3: EMP003', 'serial4: SG8P-YQKG-ZV3C', 'subject4: EMP002', 'serial5: PBF7-WZHT-WPZR', 'subject5: EMP001']
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code helps you

```
a={'serial1': 'BPCE-RNHC-25G8', 'subject1': 'EMP004', 'serial2': '7QF2-6HI9-XKZZ', 'subject2': 'EMP005', 'serial3': '8FIW-9JRB-NY4J', 'subject3': 'EMP003', 'serial4': 'SG8P-YQKG-ZV3C', 'subject4': 'EMP002', 'serial5': 'PBF7-WZHT-WPZR', 'subject5': 'EMP001'}

a=list(a.items())

for i in range(0,len(a),2):
    print(a[i+1][1]+' : '+a[i][1])
```

The output is

```
EMP004 : BPCE-RNHC-25G8
EMP005 : 7QF2-6HI9-XKZZ
EMP003 : 8FIW-9JRB-NY4J
EMP002 : SG8P-YQKG-ZV3C
EMP001 : PBF7-WZHT-WPZR
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the dictionary and print values as given below:

```py
dictValue = {'serial1': 'BPCE-RNHC-25G8', 'subject1': 'EMP004', 'serial2': '7QF2-6HI9-XKZZ',  'subject2': 'EMP005', 'serial3': '8FIW-9JRB-NY4J', 'subject3': 'EMP003',  'serial4': 'SG8P-YQKG-ZV3C',  'subject4': 'EMP002',  'serial5': 'PBF7-WZHT-WPZR', 'subject5': 'EMP001' }
n = int(len(dictValue)/2)
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print(dictValue.get('subject'+str(i)),':', dictValue.get('serial'+str(i)))
```

```
EMP004 : BPCE-RNHC-25G8
EMP005 : 7QF2-6HI9-XKZZ
EMP003 : 8FIW-9JRB-NY4J
EMP002 : SG8P-YQKG-ZV3C
EMP001 : PBF7-WZHT-WPZR
```